# HTML content being moved from one to multiple paragraphs on load

Tags: html, css

I have a simple web page that contains a content div, a paragraph inside of that, and a header, text and image inside of that.  The html looks like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <p>
        <img class="coverR" src="img/img.jpg">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        Insert description here
    </p>
</div>
```

The css for these elements looks like this:

```
#content p {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    text-indent: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#content .coverR {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-right: 8%;
    float: right;
    clear: left;
}
```

This all seems fine, but when I open the chrome inspector and look at the HTML it looks like this:

[image: In the inspector]

This wrecks my page flow, and I have no idea why it happens.  Am I doing something incredibly stupid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The end tag for a paragraph is optional.
- A paragraph cannot contain a heading, it can only contain [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1).

Thus the heading implicitly ends the paragraph, so it and everything that follows are not inside it.

There is no way to write HTML so a heading is inside a paragraph

---

Use more appropriate elements. It's hard to tell what you should be using since your example content doesn't give any context.

Comment: If you are using HTML5 the end tag is required.

I stand corrected Quentin.  Thank you.

Comment: @user2182349 — No, it isn't. Any tag that was optional in HTML 4 is still optional in HTML 5. End tags for paragraphs are only required in XHTML since XML doesn't allow for optional tags at all.

Comment: It still happens when I replace the h1 with a div

Comment: You can't have a div inside a paragraph either.

Comment: A paragraph can only contain [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1).